# How to compare the values of 2 Maps Java

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, compare, assert

At a high level, I'm trying to compare the values of 2 string maps

`Map 1: [{ExpID1, SomeExpValue1}, {ExpID2, SomeExpValue2}, ...]`

`Map 2: [{FriID1, SomeFriValue1}, {FriID1, SomeFriValue2}, ...]`

So ultimately, I'd like my comparison to be as such:

**Sudo code:**

```
if ( ExpID1.equals(FriID1) ) {
    Assert.AssertEquals(SomeExpValue1, SomeFriValue1, "Library element does not match!")
}
```

However since these are Maps, some looping is required. My real question is here, how can I correctly and efficiently loop whitout having more a bunch of embedded foreach or forloops. These seem to be super expensive. I feel my current looping is somehow wrong or unnessisarily expensive. Any help or assistance would be much appreciated.

Currently what I have is this:

```
@Test
public void testIntegration() throws Exception {

    // Get all files in directory
    File[] files = getFilesInFolder(friendlyNamesDir);

    String linkedResp = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(explanationResponsePath));
    Map<String, String> map1 = getIDTitleMapExpResponse(linkedResp, "node");

    int counter = 1;
    for(File f : files) {
        if(f.length() == 0) throw new Exception("File does not exist...");


        for(String expID : map1.keySet()) {
            logger.info("Exp ID: "+expID);

            Map<String, String> map2 = getIDNameMapFromFriendly(f.getCanonicalPath());
            for(String friendlyID : map2.keySet()) {
                logger.info(counter+" - Friendly ID: "+friendlyID+" Name: "+map2.get(friendlyID));
                if(friendlyID.equals(expID)) {
                    Assert.assertEquals(map1.get(friendlyID), map2.get(expID));
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The intersection of the key sets of the maps is the set to be iterated, and if the value from map 1 and the one from map 2 are equal, for all iterated values, your condition is true. (I have understood that there may be keys in map 1 not in map 2 and vice versa. If not, please clarify.)

Comment: @laune Yes that pretty much sums it up. I'd like to individually compare the values of the maps hence the foreach looping.

Comment: OK, so I thought that this isn't just map1.equals( map2 )...

Comment: What I'm trying to do is loop through the IDs of 2 maps, and if the current ID of map1 matches map2, compare their values (Assert they are equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that the maps are not necessarily equal, but must contain equal values for equal keys. Thus:

```
boolean alleq = true;
Set<String> key1 = new HashSet<>( map1.keySet() );
key1.retainAll( map2.keySet();
for( String s: key1 ) ){
     if( ! map1.get(s).equals( map2.get(s) ) ){
          alleq = false;
          break;
     }
}
```

You can also iterate one key set and test for the presence of the key in the other set; there's no need to iterate the second set.

```
boolean alleq = true;
for( String key1: map1.keySet() ){
    String value2 = map2.get( key1 );
    if( value2 != null && ! value2.equals( map1.get(key1) ) ){
        alleq = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is legal Java since map1.keySet().retainAll( map2.keySet() ) returns a boolean type

Comment: @mosawi Drat. Functional programming... Fixed. But you know what I mean - this should solve your problem relatively efficient, although iterating the keys of one map and checking the other one isn't really bad.

Comment: Ahh nice use of retainAll...this solves my problem and I think I just learned how to use retainAll :)

Comment: If I were to do a print of the current element (s element of iterable key1) inside that foreach loop, what would be printed? From what I understand, key1 contains all the matching keys of map1 and map2, so should s of key1 print out all the matching keys (most of them should match)? I am only seeing about 10 keys of the same keys get printed out? Does this mean only 10 keys match? There are hundreds of keys inside map1 and map2 since we are looping over multiple files.

Comment: The loop terminates as soon as a *value mismatch* for some key is found. If you need to know the number of matching keys vs. the number of matching values for matching keys you'll have to omit the break, distinguish the two cases and count both.

Comment: Whoops...my bad. In my example, the map1 I created is only a sample of a response that just contains 10 IDs (keys), so that's why that single ID got printed 10 times because that was the only one matching the keySet. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

As per Java documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

You can compare maps directly, it will make sure to check for equality for elements in them.